# Can I change the default behavior of my parent class method in my subclass method?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm learning simple python inheritance and I want that one of my parent class method default argument is changed conditionally to one of my subclass argument value, and I don't know if this is possible.

Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def doSomething(self, name, strict = True):
        if strict:
            return self.name
        else:
            return name

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).__init__(name)

        if 'changeBehavior' in kwargs:
            # Here is the thing:
            # Can I change the default value of strict to kwargs['changeBehavior']
            # in a way that when I later call doSomething(), it will behave according
            # to its new default behavior?
            def doSomething(self, name, strict = kwargs['changeBehavior']):
                super(Child, self).doSomething(strict = kwargs['changeBehavior'])
```

If this can be done in this way, is there any other method to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def doSomething(self, name, strict=True):
        print('Got strict={}'.format(strict))
        if strict:
            return self.name
        else:
            return name


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name)
        change_behavior = kwargs.get('changeBehavior')
        if change_behavior is not None:
            self.doSomething = partial(self.doSomething, strict=change_behavior)


p = Parent('name')
c = Child('name', changeBehavior=False)

p.doSomething('name')
c.doSomething('name')
```

outputs

```
Got strict=True
Got strict=False
```